# npx create-react-app not generating public and src folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

Public and src folder is not generated in my react project when I execute npx create-react-app myest.

I tried unstalling the global create-react-app using npm uinstall -g create-react-app and reinstalling it again using npm install -g create-react-app. However, after I execute npx create-react-app myest, it got stuck on the below screen

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you install `create-react-app` without the global flag?

Comment: Hi it works thanks ! guess the global flag is really deprecated

Answer (score 0):

initially tried using but not worked:
`npm rm -g create-react-app`,
`npm install -g create-react-app`,
`npx create-react-app <your-app-name>`.

below command works :
`npx --ignore-existing create-react-app Your-AppName`